# This application is not allowed to create application tokens

Tags: linkedin-api, rest

we are using grant_type as "client_credentials" and getting a below response

```
{
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

and Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded. for more information, please refer attached screenshot.
[image: k]